# TFS build - Getting error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, tfs, tfsbuild

I have configured tfs build definition for our project. And also i have added Nuget package to the solution.

When i tried to build the defination, i'm getting following error.

1. App_Start\BundleConfig.cs (7): The type or namespace name 'Optimization' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2. Global.asax.cs (10): The type or namespace name 'Optimization' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
3. App_Start\BundleConfig.cs (20): The type or namespace name 'BundleCollection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I don't know why i'm getting this error.
Could anyone please help me with this????

Comment: Looks like a missing reference (probably the NuGet package you added). Is the NuGet package added to source control or are you using package restore?

Comment: I have added it to source control.

Comment: And the .dlls got added as well? Sometimes the default filtering will exclude them from the check in

Answer (score 2):

Check your `Build definition -> Source Settings` tab. You should add path to `packages` folder where referenced packages are stored.

Comment: Say I have Dll's in Folder named `Lib` where the Project references from, how do you add in the Source Settings? I mean what should go to Source Control Folder and what for Build Agent Folder

Comment: @hiFI, `Lib` folder must be under source control. In `Source Control Folder` specify the path to the `Lib` folder under source control, for example `$/TeamProjectName/Sources/Solution/Lib`. In `Build Agent Folder` specify the path where `Lib` folder must me downloaded on build agent, for example `$(SourceDir)\Solution\Lib` or `c:\Builds\Lib`, all depends on how projects references configured.